# numpy array of zeros or empty

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing code and efficiency is very important.
Actually I need 2d array, that I am filling with 0 and 1 in for loop. What is better and why?

1. Make empty array and fill it with "0" and "1". It's pseudocode, my array will be much bigger.
2. Make array filled by zeros and make if() and if not zero - put one.

So I need information what is more efficiency:
1. Put every element "0" and "1" to empty array 
or
2. Make if() (efficiency of 'if') and then put only "1" element.

Comment: The most efficient way is to not use a `for` loop at all but to vectorize your code such that numpy can do the work. And don't ask us what's faster, time it yourself.

Comment: Usually `if-then-else` is slower than writing the value immediately. Since `if`s tend to reduce the amount of *chaining*. Nevertheless since Python itself is an interpreted language. Both will be not that much efficient. That's why you better look for ways to let numpy do the work.

Comment: I need to use for, because I need to write elements from one array to other array but in specific order. I didn't find other way to get specific order I need than for loop.

Comment: @Queen maybe you should add that `for` loop part of your problem to the question. Then we could suggest better ways (vectorized solution maybe?)

Comment: Could you share your `for` and `if-elif-else` based implementation?

Answer (score 2):

- empty() does not initialize the memory, therefore your array will be filled with garbage and you will have to initialize all cells.
- zeros() initializes everything to 0. Therefore, if your final result includes lots of zeros, this will save you the time to set all those array cells to zero manually.

I would go with zeros(). The performance bottleneck will be your python for loop anyway.

Fortunately, Numpy now as a JIT compiler, which can turn your crummy and slow python for loop into machine code:

http://numba.pydata.org/

I tried it. It's a bit rough around the edges, but the speedups can be quite spectacular compared to bare python code. Of course the best choice is to vectorize using numpy, but you don't always have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ae = np.empty(10000)
A0 = np.zeros((10000)
```

differ slightly in how memory is initially allocated.  But any differences in time will be minor if you go on and do something like

```
for i in range(10000):
    Ae[i] = <some calc>
```

or

```
for i in range(10000):
    val = <some calc>
    if val>0:
       A0[i] = val
```

If I had to loop like this, I'd go ahead and use `np.zeros`, and also use the unconditional assignment.   It keeps the code simpler, and compared to everything else that is going on, the time differences will be minor.

---

Sample times:

```
In [33]: def foo0(N):
    ...:     A = np.empty(N,int)
    ...:     for i in range(N):
    ...:         A[i] = np.random.randint(0,2)
    ...:     return A
    ...: 
In [34]: def foo1(N):
    ...:     A = np.zeros(N,int)
    ...:     for i in range(N):
    ...:         val = np.random.randint(0,2)
    ...:         if val:
    ...:             A[i] = val
    ...:     return A
    ...:
```

3 ways of assigning 10 0/1 values

```
In [35]: foo0(10)
Out[35]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
In [36]: foo1(10)
Out[36]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
In [37]: np.random.randint(0,2,10)
Out[37]: array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

times:

```
In [38]: timeit foo0(1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.06 ms per loop
In [39]: timeit foo1(1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.95 ms per loop
In [40]: timeit np.random.randint(0,2,1000)
... cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.6 µs per loop
```

The 2 loop times are nearly the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create array of zeros and fill it using if-else. Even conditions makes slow your code, reshaping empty array or concatenating it with new vectors each iteration of loop is more slower operation, because each time new array of new size is created and old array is copied there together with new vector value by value.